# Web Crawler in JAVA. java.out.lang.outofmemory Unable to create native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I am currently building this web crawler to fetch all the links of a starting url and from those links, crawler all the links,etc. I am using threads so each time the process is done, a new thread is being called, I was loading like 1000 threads and I used the thread.interrupt function and still it was not deleting a thread and creating one. I am trying to only use a thread each time or maximum two. I also noticed that once I run my crawler, my internet starts crashing meaning that websites don't load until i turn of my web crawler. I think I am sending too many http requests. If anyone knows how to limit thread or fix the error below :

java.lang.outOfMemory : Unable to create native thread

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle OUT OF MEMORY error for multiple threads in a Java Web Crawler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146236/how-to-handle-out-of-memory-error-for-multiple-threads-in-a-java-web-crawler)

Comment: That's really strange.  That duplicate is from 2009 but it seems like the _exact_ same question.  Is this sore sort of school project?

Comment: Why should we bother to answer if you can't even be bothered to formulate a clear question? (Runaway sentences, messed up punctuation, unclear wording (what does "calling a thread" mean, exactly?), no code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a thread pool instead and limit it that way. Built-in to java as well. 
Create one and add your crawler jobs to it for execution.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
```

And then:
    executor.execute(new LinkCrawler(...)); //add your link crawler here.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
Even contains a network related example.